# How to get the text from a textbox into a string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, textbox

I'm using Visual Basic 2013 and trying to make a hotspot using VB.

I have the WLAN SSID in `textbox3.text` and the key in `textbox2.text`; how would I get them into `myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments` at the positions X and Y?

This is the code I use for the button "set hotspot".

```
Dim myprocess As New Process()
    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh"
    myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=*X* key=*Y*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.Try this.

```
 Dim myprocess As New Process()
    Dim label1 As String
    Dim label2 As String
    label1 = TextBox3.Text
    label2 = TextBox2.Text
    myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh"
    myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=*x* key=*y*".Replace("*x*", TextBox3.Text).Replace("*y*", TextBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

For better code reading I'd recommend to use other textbox names. And you have to check the user input of course.

Following code should work for your needs but is not tested:

```
Dim myprocess As New Process()
Dim strSsId as string = txtSsId.Text
Dim strKey as string = txtKey.Text

myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh"
myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow " & _
  "ssid=" & strSsID & " key=" & strKey
```